# How to create input connection from Jetpack Compose Text Field?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-softkeyboard, android-input-method, inputconnection

I have my own custom keyboard created with jetpack compose, in my custom keyboard there's a feature that shows a textfield and we can type that textfield with the keyboard too, so I have to switch between 2 textfield in the same keyboard. Currently I'm using an EditText view to show the textfield and get the input connection for my keyboard with `editText.onCreateInputConnection(EditorInfo())` . This is the code:

```
val editText = EditText(context)
var inputConnection by remember{
    mutableStateOf<InputConnection?>(null)
}
LaunchedEffect(key1 = Unit){
    inputConnection = editText.onCreateInputConnection(EditorInfo()) as InputConnection
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        editText.focusable = FOCUSABLE
    }
}
Column{
    AndroidView(
        factory = { editText },
    )
    CompositionLocalProvider(
        LocalInputConnection provides  inputConnection
    ) {
        MyCustomKeyboard()
    }
}
```

All working perfectly but I'm wondering is there a way to get the input connection like this in compose version of textfield like material `TextField` or foundation `BasicTextField`? Cause I actually already have my own design system's textfield component in compose and don't want to recreate the component in XML. Thank you